# Access network storage from USB-storage-only device

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, raspberry-pi

I have an oscilloscope (and microscope) that only provide USB storage of images. Both devices run a custom embedded OS so it is impossible to use a USB wifi dongle with them.

Is there any USB device that can pretend to be a USB flash drive but map to a network folder over WIFI?

Perhaps a Raspberry Pi Zero solution? Maybe a Pi Zero could be used "as a flash drive" but something running on the Pi could copy/mirror to a folder on my network?

Comment: [This document](https://github.com/thagrol/Guides/blob/main/mass-storage-gadget.pdf). Read 3.1 to 3.5, especially 3.4.

Comment: I have that feature here and I have not seen a USB device as you propose. I just remove the USB Key and copy the information to an appropriate folder on my computer.